# Split query in several positions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website where I need to split a result query that gives me all my groups because I want to handle all the groups individualy.

This is my code ( result 6 is the query i make to obtain all the group names). But the problem is that all the result appear in the same position -> [0] zero.
This is an image of the problem [image: Image problem]

```
 <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result6)){ ?>

            <tr>
              <?php if(strlen($row['groupname'])>0){  ?>

                <?php $groups = $row['groupname']; 
                 $dividedGroups= (explode(",",$groups));
                 print_r($dividedGroups)
                ?>
                                                        </br>
            <?php } ?>
            </tr>        
      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to improve the overall explanation?  What is the resultset array?  Why are the divided strings `ee` and `ol`?  There must not be any commas if that is where they are exploded.  Please expand your question with the relevant details so we can help you.  What are you expecting to see?

Comment: I fear your question is going to get trashed if you don't improve it.  As it is currently stated, you are asking _How to use explode() in php_ and that's not going to survive on SO.  You are going to need overhaul your question to include a minimal representation of your resultset and how you wish to divide the group (aka what is your expected result).  Your account seems notorious for question with negative value, please comply with SO's question regulations and help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to split by comma as each row represent a group:

```
<?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result6)) {
        if(strlen($row['groupname'])>0) {
?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row['groupname']; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Or, if the row is not a group you can group it by groupname before displaying:

```
$results = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result6)) {
    $results[$row['groupname']] = isset($results[$row['groupname']])
         ? array_merge($results[$row['groupname']], [$row])
         : [$row];
}

print_r($results);
```

Comment: Your anwser did not helped me :/

Answer (score 0):

I guess more data is needed, but as far as I can tell you are ending with an array of arrays.

After this line:

```
$dividedGroups= (explode(",",$groups));
```

Try to add this two lines in order to transform it to a simple array:

```
$dividedGroups= array_map("array_shift",$dividedGroups);
$dividedGroups= array_map("array_values",$dividedGroups);
```

Comment: Your anwser did not helped me :/